# Change div content using buttons

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm making a slideshow but I'm stuck trying to make the div content change. I tried many ways and I'm not able to make it works.

What it is supposed to do is that when I click on an , the "apartados" change to the div with the same ID of the clicked .

There is the HTML code:

```
        <div class="cajas" id="projects-caja">

            <div class="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" data-id="1">Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-id="2">41744f</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class"apartados">

                <div class="div1">
                    <div class="espacioimagen">
                        <div class="fancyosop">
                            <p class="fancytitlep">Projects</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="div2" style="opacity:0">
                    <div class="espacioimagen">
                        <div class="fancyosop">
                            <p class="fancytitlep">41744f</p>
                        </div>
                        <img src="../uploads/41744f.png" class="fotodeslizante" />
                    </div>                        
                </div>

            </div>             
        </div>
```

And here one of the Jquery code I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".nav ul li a").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attribute("data-id");
        $(".apartados div").css("opacity", "0"); 
        $(".div" + id).css("opacity", "1"); 
    });
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: question not clear. please be more precise.

Comment: Does the page reloads when you click `<a>`?

Comment: Nope, doesn't happen.

Comment: you have data-id. so make data-id="div1" , data-id="div2"  -- grab on click -- $(this).attr("data-id");  -- and change  $("."+id ).css("opacity", "1");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @xengravity mentioned all the issues there is also a lot of HTML issues.

Anyways, here's a working sample :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".nav ul li a").click(function () {
        var target = '.div' + $(this).attr("data-id");
        $(".apartados >div").css("opacity", "0");
        $(target).css("opacity", "1");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cajas" id="projects-caja">
    <div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" data-id="1">Projects</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#" data-id="2">41744f</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="apartados">
        <div class="div1">
            <div class="espacioimagen">
                <div class="fancyosop">
                    <p class="fancytitlep">Projects</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="div2" style="opacity:0">
            <div class="espacioimagen">
                <div class="fancyosop">
                    <p class="fancytitlep">41744f</p>
                </div>
                <img src="../uploads/41744f.png" class="fotodeslizante" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see now I get the `data-id` instead of the `id`.

Also your `apartados` div has a missing `=` in the `class`. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

There a few issues here:

1. `$(this).attribute("id");` is looking for an element with an attribute of 'id'
2. `<a href="#" data-id="1">` is using 'data-id' not 'id'
3. `<a href="#" data.id="2">` is using 'data.id' not 'id' nor 'data-id'

My recommendation is to use 'data-id' for both 2 and 3 and changing your selector to: `$(this).attribute("data-id");`

Answer (score 0):

There are some html issues.. corrected the same.. Check out this fiddle...
https://jsfiddle.net/56rstuhn/

```
 $(".apartados > div").css("opacity", "0"); //ensure that only the immediate child has opacity set to zero
```